# i want to print a method in an object of on object array but cant. why?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

i am trying to understand why cant i print this method. it doesn't show me that there is any problem with my code so i can't figure out what am i missing here.

```
package practice;

class Persons{
    String name;
    int id;

    public void speak(String name,int id) {
        System.out.println("hello i am " + name + " and my id is " + id);
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class demo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Persons person[] = new Persons[5];
        person[0].speak("guy", 1);  
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating an array with length 5, however there are no elements in the array yet all the elements in the array are `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of 5 null elements. This code will throw NullPointerException.

```
Persons person[] = new Persons[5];
person[0] = new Person();
person[0].speak("guy", 1);
```

You may consider creating a constructor of type:

```
public Persons(String name,int id)
```

Or expose a public set of getters and setters.